# Read Data From Web Form to Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

I am new to VBA and I need to fetch values from [this form](https://www.moneygram.com/wps/portal/moneygramonline/home/estimator?LC=en-US) into an Excel spreadsheet. Once the user clicks on estimate, the exchange rate is displayed. The Excel spreadsheet will have column headings matching the field names in the form.

In the form, The 'Send Amount' will be 50, 100, 500, 1000, 2500 and 7000. The 'From' Country will always be 'United States'. The worksheet should be populated with all the possible selections in the other fields of the form against 'United States' and their corresponding exchange rates.

[image]

Comment: @Santosh: when I manually select values in that field (United States, US Dollar, India, 10 minute service - Indian Service, 1000) and click on estimate, I don't get any result... The website keeps on showing "Connecting...."

Comment: @SiddharthRout Even i tried and also m not getting any result. May be the site be undergoing upgradation as its weekend. But i confirm the site works, you can try after sometime or directly on monday.

Comment: @Santosh: The site is not not opening. Already tried it for two days... I give up :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I badly need to get this work done :( any insights?

Comment: Even I want to help you but the webpage is not opening after I press the `Estimate` button.

Comment: @SiddharthRout :  Seems that finally the site is up now. Just now I tried with the above selections as shown in the image posted by santosh, and clicking on 'Estimate' button shown me the exchange rate as 54.1420 INR.

Answer (score 0):

Santosh...There are two ways of doing this

- Intercept the webservice XML
- Create connection to underlying DB

You need to know DB details or create COM modules in VBA for XML (which again needs server details)

if you do not know anything at all. I would suggest go to youtube and look for "VBA com connections" or "VBA XML". There are some nice videos, handing over server details on a open forum would not be an ideal thing to do

Comment: Santosh..I can write the code but for that I would need server details and like I said. It is not advisable to give server details on an open forum. 
I can also suggest searching for some private websites that write codes for small amount of money. These would be better option than open forums. Else give a good offer to Moderator, if he has time and like your offer, just might take you up on it.

Comment: What all info i have is the URL from where data has to be pulled.

Answer (score 0):

No luck here, site writes "Connecting..." eternally.
But to sort out your issue, here's a sample code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim myIE As InternetExplorer, myDoc As HTMLDocument, mySubDoc As HTMLDivElement
Dim sVal As String, lVal As Long
```

```
Set myIE = New InternetExplorer
With myIE
    .Visible = True
    Call .navigate("http://stackoverflow.com/")
    While Not .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Wend
    Set myDoc = .document
End With
'SAMPLE
With mySubDoc
    Set mySubDoc = myDoc.getElementsByClassName("question-summary narrow").Item(0)
    sVal = CStr(mySubDoc.ID)
    lVal = CLng(mySubDoc.NodeType)
    Call MsgBox(sVal)
    Call MsgBox(CStr(lVal))
End With
On Error Resume Next
    Call mySubDoc.Close
    Call myDoc.Close
    Call myIE.stop
    Call myIE.Quit
On Error GoTo 0
Set mySubDoc = Nothing
Set myDoc = Nothing
Set myIE = Nothing
```

End SubPlease note: In Excel's VBA (ALT+F11) you have to add Reference (Tools->References) to `Microsoft HTML Object Library` and `Microsoft Internet Controls` items.
You can use the above guy to pick up values from the page source of the loaded page on your target site. So you have to set values you want, press the "Estimate" button, 'View Page Source' and look for the values' container node which you want to extract from VBA code (and add to your Excel VBA of course).
With having your site down -ie inaccessible result page- that's all I can do but with the above code you can figure out the rest of what you have to do in Excel VBA for sure.
If not, post a new question or ask here when site is up again.
Hope this helps!